# How to model a resource group with more than one resource gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a triggered child pipeline defined as

```
trigger_job:
  trigger:
    include: pipe.gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  resource_group: pipe_res
```

Currently there is only one **trigger_job** which is running at a time. I would like to have the possibility to run two or more at a time.

How can I implement this mechanism in Gitlab CI ?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a [resource groups](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/) - to run jobs one by one. So it is not possible to run several jobs in parallel for the same resource group. Also as it is written in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/#limitations):

> Only one resource can be attached to a resource group.

If you need to run several trigger job in parallel - [it is possible](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#run-a-matrix-of-parallel-trigger-jobs) to use [parallel:matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) keyword for it:

```
trigger_job:
  trigger:
    include: pipe.gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - MY_VAR: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In this example, the child pipeline will run as many times as there are values in the `MY_VAR` array.

At the moment it is not possible to use [parallel](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel) keyword with triggers.

In case if you will combine `resource_group` and `parallel:matrix` - all jobs will run one by one too.

Comment: right the parallel:matrix will not fix my issue. I saw indeed this limitation of one resource per resource group. However I was wondering if some people found a way to overcome this limitation.